# Blurry SVG in pixijs

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, svg, pixi.js

I'm trying to use PIXIJs library to display SVG image, but on a smartphone the SVG seems blurry.

[Here is a sample code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaxqvP)

```
    var $ = window.jQuery;
    var PIXI = window.PIXI;

    $(document).ready(onReady);


    var devicePixelRatio;
    var width =800;
    var height=600;

    var scale = 5;
    var renderer;
    var stage;

    var canvas;

    function onReady() {
        devicePixelRatio = $(window).devicePixelRatio;


        canvas = window.document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.style.width = width + "px";
        canvas.style.height = height + "px";

        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.appendChild(canvas);

        var svgimgtag = document.getElementById("svgimgtag");

        svgimgtag.style.top = 160 + "px";
        svgimgtag.style.left = 500 + "px";
        svgimgtag.style.width = 64 * scale + "px";
        svgimgtag.style.height = 64 * scale + "px";
        svgimgtag.src = 'https://rawgit.com/dentez/848fe2b6a8da7b3a78bacded90bd4f61/raw/89bb179753df9ee3e8b62d8c7a0c7620b6db144e/bee.svg';


        renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width , height , {
            backgroundColor: 0xFFFFFF,
            view: canvas,
            resolution: devicePixelRatio
        });

        stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
        renderer.view.style.position = 'absolute';

        requestAnimationFrame(update);

        beeTexture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('https://rawgit.com/dentez/848fe2b6a8da7b3a78bacded90bd4f61/raw/89bb179753df9ee3e8b62d8c7a0c7620b6db144e/bee.svg', undefined, undefined, scale);

        var bee = new PIXI.Sprite(beeTexture);


        bee.anchor.x = 0.5;
        bee.anchor.y = 1;
        bee.position.x = 400;
        bee.position.y = 300;
        //bunny.scale.set(1);
        stage.addChild(bee);
        renderer.resize(width, height);
    }


    function update() {

        renderer.render(stage);
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
```

On desktop browser it seems ok, but when I try this on my smartphone or android emulator the SVG renders like this:

[image]

(image on the left is PIXI-SVG; right, is an html img tag).

Maybe It is something with devicePixelRatio, it seems that the browser "Zooms-in" to fit the screen - since on desktop if I zoom-in I can emulate the same behavior.
What am I doing wrong? How is the correct way to show/scale SVG?

Answer (score 1):

This is because PIXI rasterizes SVG to the texture, according to the size of the SVG image (64x64) in this line:

```
beeTexture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage
```

Then it is scaled and, quite expectedly, this looks blurry.

You can provide sourceScale parameters to fromImage to raster it at larger scale. Or try one of the third-party libraries for PIXI to render SVG as vectors. Google returns this one, but it does not look like very actively maintained:
https://github.com/bigtimebuddy/pixi-svg

See discussion here for more info:
https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/936

Comment: Somewhere in that discussion it mentions you need `width` and `height` on your svg. This was a game changer for me. Only having `viewBox` doesn't do it, so you need `<svg width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800">`.